# Упорядочить текстовый файл

Tags: python

Есть текстовый файл с таким содержимым:

```
template1
111:222222222

template2
222:222222224

template1
111:222222222

template1
222:333333333

template2
222:555555555

template3
225:222222224
```

Нужно его привести в такой вид:

```
template1
111:222222222
111:222222222
222:333333333

template2
222:222222224
222:555555555

template3
225:222222224
```

Обратите внимание, что template отсортированы по имени. Названия template условные, тут может быть любая строка. Задача в том, чтобы объединить одинаковые строки с тем, что идет после них. В строках 225:222222224 всегда есть знак ":" (если это поможет).

Попробовал набросать такой код:

```
with open('1.txt') as file_with_data:
    list_data = file_with_data.readlines()

list_data = list(filter(None, [line.rstrip() for line in list_data]))
list_token_template = sorted(list(set(x for x in list_data if ':' not in x)))
```

Получил 2 списка:

> ['template1', 'template2', 'template3']
>
> ['template1', '111:222222222', 'template2', '222:222222224',
>   'template1', '111:222222222', 'template1', '222:333333333',
>   'template2', '222:555555555', 'template3', '225:222222224']

А дальше не придумал, как быть. Помогите решить задачу.

Comment: Вместо изображений вставляйте текст. Это может сильно помочь отвечающим, т.к. данные из изображения нельзя скопировать.

Comment: То есть у вас всегда есть строгое чередование имя/значение? Тогда это более чем легкая задача.

Comment: Roman Konoval я пытался, но текст не сохраняется в нужном мне формате (с переносами строк). Поэтому в данном случае вынужден был вставить изображения. UPD: удалось исправить.

Comment: Shamus Rezol После каждой строки есть перенос. Между блоками 2 переноса. Блок состоит из названия и значения (со знаком ":"). Нужно объединить блоки с одинаковыми названиями, чтобы значения были в одном месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> А дальше не придумал, как быть. Помогите решить задачу.

Всё просто, вот у Вас есть два списка:

```
a = ['template1', '111:222222222', 'template2', '222:222222224', 'template1', '111:222222222', 'template1', '222:333333333', 'template2', '222:555555555', 'template3', '225:222222224']
b = ['template1', 'template2', 'template3']
```

Теперь смотрим дальше, то что Вы хотите получить на выходе больше всего напоминает структуру данных - словарь:

```
d = {}
```

Заполним его ключами (template1, temp...), а в качестве значений укажем пустые списки:

```
for i in b: d[i] = []
```

А теперь пройдёмся по списку и распределим значения по ключам:

```
for i in range(0, len(a) - 1):
    if a[i] in d.keys():
        d[a[i]].append(a[i+1])
```

В итоге имеем:

```
a = ['template1', '111:222222222', 'template2', '222:222222224', 'template1', '111:222222222', 'template1', '222:333333333', 'template2', '222:555555555', 'template3', '225:222222224']
b = ['template1', 'template2', 'template3']
d = {}

for i in b: d[i] = []

for i in range(0, len(a) - 1):
    if a[i] in d.keys():
        d[a[i]].append(a[i+1])

print(d)
#{'template1': ['111:222222222', '111:222222222', '222:333333333'], 'template2': ['222:222222224', '222:555555555'], 'template3': ['225:222222224']}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from pprint import pprint

with open('file.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

result = {}
for index in range(0, len(data), 3):
    key = data[index].replace('\n', '')
    if not key in result:
        result[key] = []

    result[key].append(data[index + 1].replace('\n', ''))

pprint(result)
# {'template1': ['111:222222222', '111:222222222', '222:333333333'],
#  'template2': ['222:222222224', '222:555555555'],
#  'template3': ['225:222222224']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я уверен, что есть более органичное решение вашей задачи, но для такого я бы однозначно написал очень простенький парсер.

```
data="""template2
228:1337

template1
63337:20012

template1
1337:228

template2
26349684:2147483647

template3
99999999:11111111"""


lines=data.split('\n')

""" $result, dict   - результат программы формата {name: {key:value, ..}, ..}.
    $name, str      - последнее объявленное name.
"""
result  =dict()
name    =str()

for line in lines:

    if line.isspace() or line == '':

        """ Это пустая линия без информации.
        """
        continue

    """ Добираемся до значимой части,
        убирая пустые отступы по бокам.

        То есть "    ЯЗНАЧИМ   " превратится в "ЯЗНАЧИМ".
    """
    word=line.strip()

    """ По первому значащему символу определим:
        данная строка содержит имя или конструкцию key:value.
    """
    keychar=word[0]

    if keychar.isdigit():

        """ Это конструкция key:value,
            которая принадлежит предыдущему объявленному имени.
        """
        if name == '':

            """ Ничейных не должно быть.
            """
            raise SyntaxError("Not declared name for first.")

        (key, value)=word.split(':')

        result[name][key]=value

    else:

        """ Это имя.
        """
        name=word

        if not name in result.keys():

            result[name]=dict()

print(data, f"\n{'-'*12}\nConverted to\n", result)
```

Answer (score 1):

iterator

```
res = {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    text = filter(bool, map(str.rstrip, f))
    for key in text:
        try: val = next(text)
        except StopIteration: break
        else:
            try: res[key].append(val)
            except KeyError: res[key] = [val]
print(res)  # {'template1': ['111:222222222', '111:222222222', '222:333333333'], 'template2': ['222:222222224', '222:555555555'], 'template3': ['225:222222224']}
```

list

```
res = {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    text = list(filter(bool, map(str.rstrip, f)))
for key, val in zip(text[::2], text[1::2]):
    res.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
print(res)  # {'template1': ['111:222222222', '111:222222222', '222:333333333'], 'template2': ['222:222222224', '222:555555555'], 'template3': ['225:222222224']}
```